# Calendar calculates a wrong date

Tags: .net, calendar, globalization

Umm-ulqura calendar calculated Date is wrong as per http://www.ummulqura.org.sa/Index.aspx.  Usually it is one day ahead.

Input is 31\12\1997

As per as per http://www.ummulqura.org.sa/Index.aspx.  Output suppose to be 1\9\1418

I got 2\9\1418.

What I am missing?  Do you have a work around?

```
        UmAlQuraCalendar umAlQuraCalendar = new UmAlQuraCalendar();
        DateTime gregoDate = new DateTime(1997, 12, 31, new GregorianCalendar());
        return String.Format("{2}/{1}/{0}"
            , umAlQuraCalendar.GetDayOfMonth(gregoDate)
            , umAlQuraCalendar.GetMonth(gregoDate)
            , umAlQuraCalendar.GetYear(gregoDate));
```

Answer (score 0):

The rules for determining the UmAlQura Calendar have [changed over the years](http://www.islamicmoon.com/Moonsighting%20Ummal-Qura%20Calendar.htm). Given that the discrepancy in this website occurs in dates prior to 1420AH (April 17, 1999), it seems that this website uses later rules, rather than the rules that were in effect before 1420AH.

You can see that website is off by one when compared against published date tables:

Comparison Calendar 1356 AH to 1411 AH (14 March 1937 to 11 July 1991) (Dhahran: King Fahd University of Petroleum & Minerals Research Institute, c. 1991) [[pdf](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~gent0113/islam/downloads/ksa_calendar_1356_1411.pdf)].